# Add id based sum of total using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, How to sum the multiple column value using same id.

Example 1.

This is my excel data.

[image]

If same purchase_id found, we have to sum **dr_amount_inr** and show in one column and sum **cr_amount_inr** and show in another column.

Example 2 :

Below result is required.

[image]

**OR**

[image]

Comment: I know this question already got an answer, but you should check how to use Pivot Tables, because it does exactly what you need, but with a better design indeed.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: I'm not much aware about Pivot Tables and don't know much about excel too. Just to know is there any way to do so. that's it. I'm not able to understand some of the other answer given for various question. Thanks @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SUMIFS function as follows
Suppose

1. your purchase_id is in Column A
2. dr_amount_inr in cl=olumn B
3. cr_amount_inr in Column C
4. dr_total in column D

you need to add all the amount dr_amount_inr in column dr_total for all the same purchase id then in D1 cell use this formula:

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$10000,$A$2:$A$10000,A2)
```

It will sum all he rows of B1 to B10000, if it founds the purchase id in A2 is same in the range of A2 to A10000

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a pivot table.

When you're in Excel (I'm assuming 2010 version or later):

- click anywhere within the first table
- go to the "Insert" tab
- select Pivot Table
- when it has created the basic blank table, right-click within it
- go to PivotTable Options>Display and click "Classic PivotTable
  layout"

This means that drag-and-drop is enabled which makes it much easier. It is then possible to drag the various elements from the first table into the format that you want.

Let me know if you get stuck and I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the SUMIF formula is designed to do:
`=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)`
This will check if the values in column A match the value of A1, and then count the rows in column B for when this is true.